# Secure data with server and RSA?

Tags: mobile, key-management, rsa

the RSA system uses a private key to read the content encrypted with the public key. If I make a game for mobile, and want to save the data :

- I guess I cannot save the private key on the device.
- If I use a server, and call a php function to send me the private key, the hacker could just intercept and read the private key sent by the server to the device?
- So, playing offline is not secured? If I use a server, and let the server encrypt and decrypt everything, the server can secure what it receives, but, if it sends a base64 string back to the device, the hacker can modify the data as he wants.

So, how does it work to secure the data via the server? (the 3d option here is not really secured)?

Comment: @TildalWave thanks, any short answer to start understand the basic idea? I'll check the link.

Comment: Well here's a [video on a public key cryptography primer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QnD2c4Xovk), but I still suggest reading the previously mentioned thread here (yes, all three answers LOL).

Comment: @TildalWave OK thanks, I read it through. I would say it is above my knowledge to create a perfect protection, if the top hacker can enter and use the in-apps content, he won't buy the content anyway. But, I am concern about someone who would take some variables (like the ID of the app to connect to twitter) and make a mess with them. Can he see the .java files as the developer sees them, and just copy and paste the content of the variables like a `const int` or a `string`? Or can he only see somehow the files stored on the device?